# onDoubleClick() don't work on phone react js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, ondoubleclick

To everyone, I have a problem in my ReactJs app with the onDoubleClick() function assigned to a component, on a desktop pc my function works correctly, but on an Android mobile phone, (iPhone works fine) with the screen in vertical the function doesn't work, the screen in my phone doesn't recognize the double click as my assigned function, instead, it makes *zoom in* or *zoom out*, I want to prevent this behavior with my function.

Below is part of my code, and you can see the app in [estebmaister.github.io/react-calendar/](https://estebmaister.github.io/react-calendar/) or in the public repo with the same name.

```
      onDoubleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({
          popperAnchor: Boolean(this.popperAnchor) ? null : event.currentTarget,
        });
      };
      render() {
    return (
      <td
        key={"d" + this.props.day}
        className={`calendar-day ${this.props.currentDay}`}
        onDoubleClick={this.onDoubleClick}
      >
```

I hope you can give me a clue to fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: which mobile phone? Android or iPhone? Could you provide content of this td?

Comment: Check in your index.html if you have  `<meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    />` user-sacalable=no ->  prevents zoom in/out in mobile

Comment: Of course, the problem is in Android phone, it works in iPhone.

Comment: I'm gonna try your solution @AdrianNaranjo my index.html was `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />`

Comment: @AdrianNaranjo Your solution works for the initial problem, but it generates other, I can´t make pinch-in or pinch-out gestures on the phone.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem... I have both of mobiles (android and iPhone and it works in both) Maybe in Andoid depends of brand and gestures that they use. In my android, I can double tap without any problem... Try it in other device

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianNaranjo for the try, I will continue learning about this events and if I found an answer I will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

this solution works for when declaring components using functions rather than classes:

```js
 

    
  ....some code...
  const [waitingClick, setWaitingClick] = 
  useState(null);
  const [lastClick, setLastClick] = useState(0);
  const processClick = (e) => {
    if(lastClick&&e.timeStamp - lastClick < 250 && 
  waitingClick){
      setLastClick(0);
      clearTimeout(waitingClick);
      setWaitingClick(null);
      console.log('double click')}
      else{
        setLastClick(e.timeStamp);
        setWaitingClick(setTimeout(()=>{
        setWaitingClick(null);
        }, 251))
        console.log('single click')
        
      }
      
    }
 ....some code...
  <component  onClick={(e)=>processClick(e)}></>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for double click. Please note that `onDoubleClick` does not work in mobile version of almost all browsers. And you need to use `onTapStart` and so on. But I would like to introduce a simple work around that I have tested in Chrome, FireFox and Safari and it works perfect. I made a double click via `onClick` event for a `img` tag.

```js
render() => {
this.watingClick = null; // a reference to timeout function
this.lastClick = 0; // a watchdog for difference between 2 clicks
    return ( <img
             onClick={(e) => {
              if (
                this.lastClick &&
                e.timeStamp - this.lastClick < 250 &&
                this.watingClick
              ) {
                this.lastClick = 0;
                clearTimeout(this.watingClick);
                console.log("Do the steps to respond double click");
                this.watingClick = null;
              } else {
                this.lastClick = e.timeStamp;
                this.watingClick = setTimeout(() => {
                  this.watingClick = null;
                  console.log("Do the steps to respond single click");
                }, 251);
              }
            }}
            />
     );
}
```

Here, I assumed time difference between 2 clicks is 250 mili seconds, you can increase it even to 300, however, decreasing this value in most browsers does not work.